# Modal on mobile ugly

Tags: css, modal-dialog

Good Day,

I have my .modal CSS code as such

```
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 1050;
    width: 560px;
    margin-left: -280px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    *border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
     border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    outline: 0;
}
```

However, it looks like this on mobile

[image]

I need a way for the modal to resize.

Comment: you have a fixed width in your modal's css.  consider media queries to set an appropriate width depending on the screen width of the devie

Comment: Or alternatively use a %-based width and set a max-width so it doesn't get too big on desktop screens. E.g. width: 90%; max-width:560px;

Comment: An example of media query as msturdy mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/upNn9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with two ways to archive this:

1) Use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upNn9/)

```css
.modal {
/* original code */
}
@media (max-width:622px) {
    .modal {
        left:5%;
        margin-left:0px;
        width:90%;
    }
}
```

`622px` is the result of `560px/0.9`;

2) Use percentage and `max-` CSS attributes

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upNn9/1/)

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper"><div class="modal">Some text</div></div>
```

```css
.modal-wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    top:10%;
    left:50%;
    width:560px;
    max-width:90%;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:1050;
}
.modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:-50%;
    /* background colors and stuffs */
}
```

Method 1 makes least change to your code, but if you ever change your mind about the `560px` limit, you'll also have to take care of the media query `max-width` value;

Method 2 makes quite some change to your code, but if you ever change your mind about the `560px` limit, you should be able to change it fast (even [with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/upNn9/2/)).